# What is the difference between thread and service in android , when downloading an image

Tags: android, multithreading, service

What is the difference between thread and service in android,when downloading an image

Comment: I searched. but not clearly understand. I have used thread and service for same work. but both are working. I don't understand the difference between them. please if you can give one example to understand thread and service. when should I use service instead of thread, iI can't understand

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of difference between Normal thread and a Service

**Service**: Due to android component it runs on UI thread but without any view shown to user. It runs in background with the same kind of property that an activity have, like you cannot run network operations (downloading image, calling web service) in service for that you have to use Thread which will run on worker thread other than UI thread.

**Thread**: Its an independent path of execution which can consist network operation, complex coding, huge amount of data transfer and accept. Thread is not related to android but in android it is used to perform different task. You can download an image on Thread but to show it on any UI part you have to update downloaded image on UI thread using `runOnUIThread` method

Please let me know if this explanation clears your doubt. If not let me know which part you did not understand and what exactly is your question.

Comment: Thank you. yes I understand the difference. one confusion still I have, when should I use service instead of thread. Suppose I'm downloading an image using thread in Activity A, if you move to Activity B will the thread work, (where in same situation service is working).

Comment: here you said same kind of property that an activity have. property means I did not get clearly

Comment: suppose we are using service to download an image (using worker thread) and after download, can we show that downloaded image on any UI part directly. please help me to get clear idea. I have spent lot of time. and even i wrote some code in my system, both of the situation I'm getting the same result

Comment: Please update your question with the question you have asked in comment so that I can properly provide you answer of it.

Answer (score 0):

With rare exceptions, you should never explicitly create a `Thread`.  Threads are expensive and prone to programmer error.  Use `AsyncTask` because it handles the complexity of thread safety and provides the optimization of thread pooling.  Or better yet, if network activity is your reason for doing work outside the main thread, use one of the many network libraries that manages all of these concerns for you.  Which approach is fastest is not something that can be answered generally, and [should never even be a concern](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?PrematureOptimization) until you've tried the simple and clear solution and demonstrated that its performance is inadequate.

Regardless of how you make your network activity asynchronous, any network activity that is not started and completed (or cancelled) within the lifetime of a single `Activity` instance needs to be hosted in something else.  If it only needs to survive across configuration changes, host it in a retained `Fragment`.  If it needs to survive between different activities, host it in a `Service`.  When choosing between these options, remember that your `Activity` may be destroyed any time it goes into the background or backstack.

Comment: Why one should not create Thread explicitly? Why should we use AsyncTask? Which one is faster?

Comment: @AbhinavSinghMaurya The important question is which is easier to use and less prone to programmer error.

Comment: The question I have asked are basic and without knowing basic your question is a kind of half knowledge.

Comment: @AbhinavSinghMaurya I edited the answer to explain better.